# i need to perform a oracle trigger with exception which has dependency on two tables but need to perform trogger on only one table

Tags: oracle, exception, triggers

I had the below requirement

`[image: TABLE1]

[image: TABLE2]

I had 2 tables, while before inserting or updating on table 1 we need to check a trigger with below conditions `where id should not be null and id needs to exist in table 2  qid column and length of id should be greater than length 6`

If the above cases fails need to print an exception in the same trigger ..

please help me in above trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a *trigger* issue, but various *constraints*:

- **foreign key** will check whether ID exists
- `NOT NULL` will make sure it isn't empty
- **check** constraint will check its length (but that's irrelevant as foreign key constraint handles that anyway)

So:

```
SQL> create table table2
  2    (qid     number constraint pk_2 primary key,
  3     name    varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table table1
  2    (id1     number constraint pk_1 primary key,
  3     id      number constraint fk_12 references table2 (qid) not null,
  4     name    varchar2(10),
  5     address varchar2(10),
  6     --
  7     constraint ch_len_id check (length(id) > 6)  --> you can skip that
  8    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

If it must be a trigger, then:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_t1
  2    before insert or update on table1
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    if :new.id is null then
  8       raise_application_error(-20000, 'ID can not be NULL');
  9
 10    elsif length(:new.id) <= 6 then
 11       raise_application_error(-20001, 'ID length must be greater than 6');
 12
 13    else
 14       select count(*)
 15         into l_cnt
 16         from table2
 17         where qid = :new.id;
 18
 19       if l_cnt = 0 then
 20          raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID does not exist in table2');
 21       end if;
 22    end if;
 23  end trg_biu_t1;
 24  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ..I got your point.. but the requirement is not to create  a constraint .. but need to create a trigger to check all these conditions and display an exception if not satisfied

Comment: Have a look at edited answer.